# Passing an array to function error?

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double avrage(int array[5]);

int main(void)
{
    int arr[5] = {10,20,30,40,50};
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    printf("Avg = %f",avrage(arr));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

double avrage(int array[5])
{
    int i,sum=0;
    double avg=0;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        sum = sum + array[i];
    }
    avg = sum / 5;
    return avg;
}
```

I have written code for passing an array to a function to get average of array element .
but i am getting 3 errors that I am not understanding  Can somebody help me to resolve these errors
forgive me for my poor English

Errors:

1. Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
   **conflicting types for 'avrage'** Array_Argument.c
   /Array_Argument/src line 58 C/C++ Problem
2. Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
   **expected declaration or statement at end of input**  Array_Argument.c    /Array_Argument/src line 67 C/C++ Problem
3. Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
   **too few arguments to function 'avrage'**   Array_Argument.c    /Array_Argument/src line 54 C/C++ Problem

Comment: [Works for me.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lxbTOANZ5v5OgjKb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`avg = sum / 5.0;` Otherwise integer arithmetic will truncate the result. Apart from that code is alright.

Ultimately your code boils down to `double avrage(int *array)`. Arrays decays into pointer to the first element.